# How can I give Users the permission to Access all subdocuments and sub collections of a collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wondered how you can give a User the permission to Access all sub collections and documents of a collection in **Firebase Firestore.**
Example:
If I have the following Code in my Rules File

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /LogInCodes/{codes} {
        allow read: if true
      allow write: if false
    }
}
```

, the User can read `/LogInCodes/firstDocument`, but  not `/LogInCodes/firstDocument/subfolder/subdocument`. How can I give the User the Permission to Access all following sub collections and documents?

Hope you understood me.
Thanks, Boothosh

Answer (score 2):

You can give access to a specific subcollection :

```js
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /LogInCodes/{codes} {

        allow read: if true
        allow write: if false

         // Explicitly define rules for the 'subcollextion1' subcollection
        match /subcollextion1/{landmark} {
          allow read, write: if <condition>;
        }
    }
}
```

or to all subcollections:

```js
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /LogInCodes/{codes} {

        allow read: if true
        allow write: if false

         // Matches any document in any subcollection.
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure).

Also take care witch version of security rules you use. There are slight differences. But you can define on your own what version you want to use.